# NUnit Test Per Database Row?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I don't know if this is possible, but I'll go ahead and explain what I'm trying to do.

I want to create a test fixture that runs a test with 5 different types of inputs that come from a database.

```
TestFixture
    Test using input1
    Test using input2
    Test using input3
    Test using input4
    Test using input5
```

This way, I can see from the NUnit GUI exactly which input is causing the failure, but I don't know how to do this.  Currently, I have something set up like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tester{
    [Test]
    public void RunTest(){
        var inputs = db.inputs.where(a=>a.id < 6).ToList();
        bool testSuccess=true;
        foreach(var input in inputs){
            bool success = RunTheTest(input);
            if(success==false){
                testSuccess=false;
            }
        }
        //Tell NUnit that the entire test failed because one input failed
    }
}
```

In this case, in NUnit, I see:

```
Tester
    RunTest
```

And even though RunTest tries 5 different inputs, I only know if there was one or more inputs that failed, but I have no idea of which input failed.  Basically what I'm asking is if it's possible to dynamically create tests that show up in the NUnit GUI based on whatever I want to grab from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the foreach loop you can do
`Assert.True( success, string.Format("Input: {0}", input ))`;

Alternately you can try the [ValueSourceAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=valueSource&r=2.5.10) with a sourceType being a helper class that has a method that returns an IEnumerable named sourceName. The implementation of this method should fetch the input values from DB.

Comment: I consider RunTest as one test, the RunTheTest is just a helper method. So the first assertion in the test will fail the entire test. In unit testing you should not run multiple tests as one.

Comment: The first Assert that fails will cause the test to end

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [TestCaseSource](http://automaticchainsaw.blogspot.com/2010/04/unit-test-all-enum-values-with-nunit.html) attribute.  This will let you define another method that, at runtime, will create test cases for each item returned from the source method.